# Issue combining 5 minute time intervals into hourly time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is my first time posting so excuse me if my post isn't the best...

I previously looked at this to combine my 5 minute intervals into hourly intervals and show the volumes per every hour.
[Combine 5 minute timeframes into hourly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172153/combine-5-minute-timeframes-into-hourly).

Here is a snippet of the CSV data I am working with. The delimiter is a comma. Data goes all the way from June 20117 through to the end of 2021.

| datestamp | timestamp | det_vol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-01 | 13:45 | 582 |
| 2017-06-01 | 13:50 | 592 |
| 2017-06-01 | 13:55 | 578 |
| 2017-06-01 | 14:00 | 544 |
| 2017-06-01 | 14:05 | 521 |

I read the data in using `pd.read_csv()` and sorted through the values to obtain all the volume readings from the month of August for 2017

```
vds2 = vds2[(vds2['datestamp'].dt.year == 2017) & (vds2['datestamp'].dt.month == 8)]
vds2 = vds2.rename(columns={'det_vol': 'Volume'})
vds2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['datestamp']).dt.date
vds2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['timestamp']).dt.time
vds2 = vds2[['Date','Time','Volume']]
vds2 = vds2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This got me to my final dataframe:

```
          Date       Time    Volume
0   2017-08-01      00:00        57
1   2017-08-01      00:05        97
2   2017-08-01      00:10        79
3   2017-08-01      00:15        63
4   2017-08-01      00:20        87
... ... ... ...
```

However when I try to implement the following I get an error on the first line

```
vds2.index = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Date'] + ' ' + vds2['Time'])
vds2 = vds2.resample('H').agg({'Volume':'sum'})

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'
```

I thought maybe the issue was the format of the `Date` and `Time` whic is why I tried implementing

```
vds2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Date']).dt.date
vds2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Time']).dt.time
```

But I still got a similar error...

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

I'm sure this is quite simple but would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hello.  Can you provide a subset of your data frame data if it is embedded in your program or data file data if it is coming from a "csv" or other file?

Comment: It is coming from a CSV that I then cleaned up slightly to get the dataframe I am working with in the example. Sorry for my lack of knowledge but what is typically the best way of sharing data? Through a shareable link like Google Drive or some other form?

Comment: If you could add in a small sample of the beginning of your CSV file including the first row that has the column names and then four or five rows of data after that in your narrative above that would help.  And, please indicate what the delimiter is (comma, tab, or other character).  Also, it always is good to provide a minimal version of your code so that the community can test it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated the post to add in some more detail. Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out your additional code and creating a small "CSV" file out of your sample, I got the same unwanted error.  I am not certain, but in searching what the appeared to be happening is that the following line of code was storing your timestamp as a string.

```
vds2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['timestamp']).dt.time
```

The subsequent call to the "pd.to_datetime" function was falling over.

When I had been trying out various scenarios and getting output, I was not converting the date stamp or timestamp fields.  I just left them as is.  So what I did was just rename the columns after importing the data from the "CSV" file.  Following is my sample code, based upon your program but not doing any data element conversion.  I am just renaming the columns.

```
import pandas as pd

vds2=pd.read_csv('DateTime.csv')

print(vds2)

#vds2 = vds2[(vds2['datestamp'].dt.year == 2017) & (vds2['datestamp'].dt.month == 8)]
vds2 = vds2.rename(columns={'det_vol': 'Volume'})
vds2 = vds2.rename(columns={'datestamp': 'Date'})
vds2 = vds2.rename(columns={'timestamp': 'Time'})
vds2 = vds2[['Date','Time','Volume']]
vds2 = vds2.reset_index(drop=True)

vds2.index = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Date'] + ' ' + vds2['Time'])
vds2.index.name = 'Date and Time'
vds2 = vds2.resample('H').agg({'Volume':'sum'})

rslt_df = vds2[vds2['Volume'] > 0]

print(rslt_df)
```

Running this program over the sample data resulted in the following output on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/DateTime$ python3 DateTime.py 
   index datestamp timestamp  det_vol
0      0  6/1/2017     13:45      582
1      1  6/1/2017     13:50      592
2      2  6/1/2017     13:55      578
3      3  6/1/2017     14:00      544
4      4  6/1/2017     14:05      521
                     Volume
Date and Time              
2017-06-01 13:00:00    1752
2017-06-01 14:00:00    1065
```

Perhaps someone above my pay grade can better explain what was happening when your program attempted to convert the time data from your data frame to a timestamp, but it looks like you don't need to even go through the datetime function at that point.  It looks like you can just rename the columns to your liking and continue summarizing and processing.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Looks like you were right, I re-ran my code and commented out

`vds2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Date']).dt.date
vds2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(vds2['Time']).dt.time`

No errors this time.

Comment: You are welcome.  I wish you well on your progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['datestamp'] + df['timestamp'])
>>> df.resample('H').det_vol.sum()
2017-06-01 13:00:00    1752
2017-06-01 14:00:00    1065
Freq: H, Name: det_vol, dtype: int64
```

You need to have the datetime in your index for resample to work.

Comment: Yeah, my issue is that when I try creating an index made up of the datestamp + timestamp the following error gets raised.

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'str'`

Comment: Make them both string with Series.astype(str) then add them together as above.